# How to disambiguate subdirs with the same name in the Qt Creators' Projects list?

Tags: qt, qmake

My Qt project has 2 subdirs/subprojects with the same name. Their directories are `myproject/node` and `myproject/compiler/test/node`.

The problem (or annoyance) is that, in the Projects list in Qt Creator, both subdirs are listed as "node". So you have to open them up to figure out which is which.

myproject.pro is like this:

```
TEMPLATE = subdirs

SUBDIRS += \
    compiler_test_node \
    node \
        ...

compiler_test_node.subdir = compiler/test/node
node.depends = compiler_vuo_compile
...
```

Without renaming the `myproject/compiler/test/node` directory, is there a way to make it show up with a different name in the Projects list?